# Сортировка строк в файле

Tags: python, сортировка, текстовые-файлы

Приветствую участников форума. Дана следующая задача: переписать строки файла out1.txt в файл out2.txt, отсортировав их по увеличению длин. Обработку файлов производить построчно, содержимое файла читать в память целиком запрещается. Списки, множества, словари, кортежи для сортировки не использовать.

Я хотела бы, во-первых, узнать, есть ли какие-либо источники информации, где рассказывается, как правильно обрабатывать содержимое текстового файла (как производить сортировку строк без использования массивов, как перезаписать строки в файле в обратном порядке без использования дополнительного файла и т.д.) и попросить оценить написанный мною код для решения поставленной задачи (подскажите, как улучшить, избавиться от "костыльности" и т.д.). Вот, собственно, он:

```
with open('out1.txt','r') as file1, open('out2.txt','w') as file2:
    line = file1.readline()
    count = previous_line = 0
    max_line = ''
    while line != '':
        count += 1
        if len(line) >= len(max_line):
            max_line = line
        line = file1.readline()
    line_number = None
    for i in range(count):
        file1.seek(0)
        cur_min_line = max_line
        pos = 0
        for j in range(count):
            next_line = file1.readline()
            if previous_line < len(next_line) < len(cur_min_line) and j != line_number:
                cur_min_line = next_line
                pos = j
            elif len(next_line) == previous_line and j != line_number:
                file2.write(next_line)
        file2.write(cur_min_line)
        line_number = pos
        previous_line = len(cur_min_line)
        if cur_min_line == max_line:
            break
```

Заранее прошу прощения, если мои вопросы показались странными или глупыми, но я уже долго пытаюсь найти то, что мне нужно, и, увы, пока тщетно. А это именно то, что требуется уметь делать в моём вузе на текущем этапе обучения.

Comment: Давайте сначала уточним. Что вы подразумеваете под "как производить сортировку строк без использования массивов". Вы же надеюсь понимаете, что даже один файл отсортировать без того, что-бы его временно весь загрузить в память, там отсортировать и результат вернуть в файл -  теоретически можно, но заплатить за это придется на насколько порядков (!)  большим временем выполнения чем все это сделать "через  массив"? В чем причина такого ограничения?  Если же ваш массив столь огромен, что в память не помещается-то используется разделение его на части, их сортировка с последующим слиянием.

Comment: @passant, это ограничение - часть условия задачи, которую задал преподаватель в вузе, поэтому по-другому я решить, к сожалению, не могу (т.е. не разрешают по-другому решать).

Comment: Ваш вопрос совсем не глупый, а глубокий из раздела [внешних сортировок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе почти то же, что и у вас.
Только никакие строчки считать не надо. Сначала за первое чтение находим минимальную длину строк. Потом снова идём по файлу и выписываем строки этой длины в выходной файл одновременно запоминая следующую минимальную длину (которая больше предыдущей). Повторяем сей процесс пока находятся строки большей длины.

```
with open('out1.txt','r') as input_file:
    min_len = min(map(len, input_file))  # в этой строке используются только генераторы, так что файл целиком не зачитывается
    with open('out2.txt','w') as output_file:
        while min_len != float('inf'):
            input_file.seek(0)
            next_min_len = float('inf')
            for line in input_file:
                line_len = len(line)
                if line_len > min_len and line_len < next_min_len:
                    next_min_len = line_len
                elif line_len == min_len:
                    output_file.write(line)
            min_len = next_min_len
```

Ну и обратная сортировка до кучи.

```
with open('out1.txt','r') as input_file:
    max_len = max(map(len, input_file))
    with open('out2.txt','w') as output_file:
        while max_len:
            input_file.seek(0)
            next_max_len = 0
            for line in input_file:
                line_len = len(line)
                if line_len > next_max_len and line_len < max_len:
                    next_max_len = line_len
                elif line_len == max_len:
                    output_file.write(line)
            max_len = next_max_len
```

Answer (score 0):

А так не проще:

```
str_ln=[]
with open('out1.txt','r') as file1:
    st=0
    for line in file1:
        str_ln.append ([len(line),st])
        st=st+len(line)+1
str_ln.sort(key=lambda i: i[0])   
with open('out1.txt','r') as file1, open('out2.txt','w') as file2:
    for i in str_ln:
        file1.seek(i[1])
        file2.write(file1.read(i[0]-1)+'\n')
```

Comment: Списки запрещены в постановке задачи.

Comment: На Windows строки разделяются парой символов. Ваш код будет промахиваться в операции `file1.seek`. Это причина по которой не надо смешивать `seek` и чтение файлов в недвоичном режиме.